# Create Extension Method of ICollection<T> after .Count()

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Im trying to create a very simple extension method that returns true or false if the count of any `Collection` is equals to one. I have the corresponding Method. But that method runs the `.Count()` inside of it. The idea is to run only the validation after the count, for example: `myList.Count().EqualsToOne();`

I dont know if it have something to do with receiving a func an invoke it (tho it would be the same I think).

This is the implementation:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool EqualsToOne<T>(this ICollection<T> sequence)
    {
        int count = sequence.Count();

        if(count == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee emp = new Employee() { Id = 1 };

    List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>()
    {
        emp,
    };

    //The idea should be lstEmployee.Count().EqualsToOne()
    bool result = lstEmployee.EqualsToOne(); 

    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();

    lstEmployee.Add(emp);

    result = lstEmployee.EqualsToOne();

    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: Does `ICollection<T>.Count()` return `ICollection<T>`? No, it returns `int`. If you want to define an extension method to be called on the value returned by `ICollection<T>.Count()`, you want an extension method `public static bool EqualsToOne(this int x) => x == 1;`

Comment: I'm hoping this is just for learning purposes... I can't imaging wanting to type `.Count().EqualsToOne()` instead of `.Count() == 1`..

Comment: A better use for an extension method here would be to have an extension method that replaced `.Count()` and checked if the collection contained exactly a specific number of elements, such as `.ContainsExactly(1)` or any such number. This could be optimized for an early exit if it finds N+1 items, instead of counting them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you would want this. But here it is: `Count()` returns an `int`, and that `int` is what you want to extend:

```
public static bool EqualsToOne(this int i) => i == 1;
```

---

But in fact, if this is only about instance of `ICollection<T>`, this interface already provides a **property** `Count`. There is no need to use linq's `Count()` extension. Simply `collection.Count == 1` is all you need.

If you want to extend this to other `IEnumerable<T>` instances, I would avoid `Count()`ing the whole sequence if you just want to know it's exactly one element.

So I'd change your first implementation to this:

```
public static bool SequenceHasExactlyOneElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    using(var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        return enumerator.MoveNext() && !enumerator.MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: I would even suggest to generalize the implementation by having one extension method that checks that the collection contains exactly N elements, and then an extension method for the special case of 1 which just calls the former.

Comment: However, I can't say I ever have had the need for any of these. Usually it is "0, or more".

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen in fact I remember we have an extension that checks for exactly 1, though I forgot what we needed it for. And the further generalization is left as an exercise :)

Comment: `.Single()` perhaps? No, that's not it.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen just thought about it, ok maybe we had a "has 0 or one" or something....without throwing exceptions etc.

Comment: "has at least n elements" -> `.Skip(n).Any()` is handy, if you have somebody around who gets upset when a menu item says "Close All Tabs" but there's only one tab.